# android - libgdx - how can I show colors list in selectbox?

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm creating a game for android phones in which I would like to have dropdown for selecting player color. For drop-down I'm using SelectBox and I have put list of colors in SelectBox but it is showing hex value of color, and not the real color. Maybe I should just put some sort of a shape inside SelectBox that has that color. It's hard for me to explain because I'm beginner at using libgdx and game development.

this is what I'm trying to achieve: [imgur.com/0Hxba98](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6iLq.jpg)

Comment: can you elaborate your problem in bit more details and don't be ashamed of english. we are developer not grammar nazi.

Comment: I'm creating a game for android phones in which I would like to have dropdown for selecting player color. For dropdown I'm using SelectBox and I have put list of colors in SelectBox but it is showing hex value of color, and not the real color. Maybe I should just put some sort of a shape inside SelectBox that has that color.
It's hard for me to explain because I'm begginer at using libgdx and game development.

Comment: this is what I'm trying to achieve: http://imgur.com/0Hxba98

Comment: now put your comments onto the question sections. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectBox is generic class, that can be anything like String.

```
SelectBox<T> sel=new SelectBox<T>(skin);
```

If you want dropDown Should be Name of Color than T should be String.
and create array for your different string and pass into SelectBox.

Comment: thanks for the advice :) I was thinking about that but I wanted to make that part like picture in question. On second thought, your way is simpler and faster to accomplish.

Comment: you're welcome. SelectBox is generic so you can take different Sprite for your different color of pictures and use with SelectBox.